# What is standard way to implement the contact sync server using CardDAV

Tags: sql-server-2008, server, synchronization, contacts, carddav

I am looking to setup a CardDAV server which will sync my contacts from a database to a client device using a standard protocol.

I am currently using ASP.net for web and MSSQL 2008 for the backend, now I want to develop an access point where the user can directly add a server url and authentication details to sync the contacts.

I am looking for a CardDAV server which will work with my current setup. Please help me to find the standard solution, all the current CardDAV servers are in PHP and MySQL .

Comment: Your question is missing what you tried and even what your actual issue is. What is 'all the current cardDav server are in php and mysql' supposed to mean? There are FOSS CardDAV servers for pretty much any language available, if you even need one. What part of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6352 do you have issues with?

Comment: I have the application in ASP.Net using c#, where user creates contacts and those are stored in MSSQL database, So want to support user to sync contacts from their mobile devices as like Google contacts.  So I am looking for solution who has the MSSQL Support to sync the contacts.

Comment: Yes, so with which part of implementing RFC 6352 do you have a problem with? What did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: Hnh thank you for your comment, But my client want to use the already  developed solution with few modification to merge our DB.   Not to develop full functionality. 
If you have any solution that using MSSQL as backend, please let me know- Thank you Ramdas

Comment: You can find a list of implementations over here http://caldav.calconnect.org/implementations.html, but none of them seems to be .NET. But why not just roll your own? CardDAV isn't that hard and G seems to suggest that there are .NET vCard libraries available.